# Secure WCF not working with non windows Clients iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, soap, https

I create WCF SOAP service to work with my iPhone application.It's work fine with Service Client "Coded Client" and WCF Test Client tool in VS,but with iPhone or Java or PHP not working .
The WCF it's work on https configuration

with binding like this

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
          establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and behavior like:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="HR_Service.Service">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint" contract="HR_Service.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"
            httpsGetBinding="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

and ASP.net session compaability

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and my iPhone is like this

```
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; // Or whatever logic
}

+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host 
{ 
}
```

To accept the certificates form the server,Then SOAP envelop

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soap:Body><Authenticate><userid>username</userid><password>pass</password></Authenticate></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];
```

then the envelop

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebsite.com/Service/Service1.svc"];                           
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];                         
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];              
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/Authenticate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]]; 
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```

the NSURLConnectionDelegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Data has been loaded");

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"Respose Data :%@",responseString) ;


}
```

the connection always success but the response data come empty always

Answer (score 0):

your soapMessage is wrong

you are using wrong tag

use "Authenticate" tag instead of "test" tag in soamMessage String